# Why this structure should have 48 bytes

Tags: delphi, winapi, alignment

I tried to translate some new part of winuser.h header to Delphi. 
Why this structure is expected to be 48 bytes (only this size was accepted by the corresponding function). With 4-bytes boundary, it looks like it should have 40 bytes.

```
  typedef struct tagGESTUREINFO {
      UINT cbSize;                    
      DWORD dwFlags;                  
      DWORD dwID;                     
      HWND hwndTarget;                
      POINTS ptsLocation;             
      DWORD dwInstanceID;             
      DWORD dwSequenceID;             
      ULONGLONG ullArguments;         
      UINT cbExtraArgs;               
  } GESTUREINFO, *PGESTUREINFO;
```

If it's related to 8-bytes boundary? if so is it relevant to any case where ULONGLONG appears structures?

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The structure is 48 bytes big because the Windows API requires 8-byte alignment.  This is simply the convention adopted by Microsoft Windows; [MSDN says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383745%28VS.85%29.aspx#controlling_structure_packing) it's because the largest integral type currently supported is 8 bytes big, so 8-byte alignment ensures that all integral types are properly aligned.

(Keep in mind that header files such as winuser.h specify an [API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface), but to actually use an already-compiled library using that API, you need an [ABI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface), which includes details like calling conventions and structure alignment.)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is the default packing of 8 which moves the ullArgument member up to get it aligned properly.  There are 4 padding bytes there to get it from offset 28 to 32.  And 4 padding bytes at the end to ensure that an array of structures still has that member aligned properly.

Answer (score 3):

Note that this type is defined in the Delphi 2010 Windows.pas already.

Comment: Yes, I know, but I manage to do this for a much much earlier version